# Why is the "label" attribute not working for the "option" element?

Tags: html, css

```html
<select>
  <option label="Volvo">Volvo (Latin for "I roll")</option>
  <option label="Saab">Saab (Swedish Aeroplane AB)</option>
  <option label="Mercedes">Mercedes (Mercedes-Benz)</option>
  <option label="Audi">Audi (Auto Union Deutschland Ingolstadt)</option>
</select>
```

I am using Chrome, and the "label" attribute isn't working for the "option" elements.

[image]

Note that, adding "name" to the "select" element, or wrapping it in a "form" does not change anything.

Comment: It does when I test it in Chrome 83. Either there is something different about your real test case, or a bug in the browsers you are testing it in. https://imgur.com/a/tGp2GZI

Comment: the documentation from where you copied your example https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_label is working as intended on chrome. So this ' problem ' cannot be reproduced

Comment: It's working on the snippet too, but when i try it on my browser, it's not showing. I guess there's a bug in the browser.

Comment: @IloveCoffee — Assuming that you are using *the same browser* to look at the snippet and your other test case, then it definitely isn't the browser.

Comment: What could it be then? There is nothing different about my test. I literally just copy-pasted the exact same code from above into my text editor. Here is a picture of my text editor and the browser output: https://imgur.com/a/LI10PuT